# Limiting joined table to 4 rows and returning the results in json with postgresql and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So far, I haven't been able to get past the `error aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls` and I haven't found a way to limit the joined table that wouldn't trigger that error.

I have tried `func.count(Video.id).label('rn')` in place of `func.row_number().over(partition_by=role.c.movie_id).label('rn')` which gives me the error: `aggregate function calls cannot be nested` and moving the Actor table into it's own subquery which is giving me the error `AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'type'`

```
sub_query = db.session.query(
    func.json_build_object(
        'movie_name', Movie.movie_name,
        'movie_year', Movie.year,
        'movie_description', Movie.description,
        'Actors', func.array_agg(
            func.json_build_object(
                'actors_name', Actor.name,
                'actors_age', Actor.age,
                'rn', func.row_number().over(partition_by=role.c.movie_id).label('rn')
            )
        )
    )
).group_by(Movie.movie_name, Movie.year, Movie.description, role.c.movie_id)\
.join(role, (role.c.movie_id == Movie.id)).join(Actor, (role.c.actor_id == Actor.id)).subquery()
query = db.session.query(sub_query).filter(text('rn <= 4'))
```